# Disable auto rotation

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Xcode and Swift. (Xcode 7.2, Swift 2.0) My first project contains a navigation controller and 3 other view controllers: A, B and C. I do not want any views to auto rotate. I want A and B permanently in portrait and C permanently in landscape. In General -> Deployment Info -> Device Orientation I have checked Portrait and Landscape left. In each VC I have code like this in viewDidLoad.

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

and the following method…

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Each view starts out in the desired orientation. However the darn thing keeps auto rotating.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you're describing. Different view controllers at different depths in a navigation controller cannot have different fixed orientations. It isn't supported.

The only way to give a view controller a different fixed orientation from the previous view controller is as a *presented* view controller, not a view controller *pushed* onto a navigation controller's stack.

Also, this line:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

would likely get your app rejected at the App Store. You are not allowed to set the device's orientation like this.

Answer (score -2):

First way : If you don't want to rotate any VC in your project just uncheck the Device Orientation properties in your Targets window. 
[image]

Second way: If you are using **UINavigationController** and if you want to call `shouldAutorotate()` function you should create a **custom UINavigationController** class and import the following code,

Like this, in your **customNavigationController** class,

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
   return false
}
```

In this way you can change to another NavigationController's viewControllers to allow oriantations